# Image not being displayed with pil

Tags: python, path, operating-system, python-imaging-library, filepath

I am trying to open the image from this directory but am not been able to. It gives me the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1840203b5591> in <module>
      4 
      5 file = path+'\\'+a
----> 6 Image.open(file).show()
      7 #files=os.listdir(path)
      8 #emoji=random.choice(files)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2807 
   2808     if filename:
-> 2809         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2810         exclusive_fp = True
   2811 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/laura/Desktop/TheLab/nft/Emojis\\031-happy-2.png'
```

This is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import random
import numpy as np

path = r"/home/laa/Desktop/TheLab/nft/Emojis"
a=random.choice(os.listdir(path))
print(a)

file = path+'\\'+a
Image.open(file).show()
```

I don't know what's hapenning whenever a is printed it shows the name of the image with its .png extension but it is not displaying it later.

Comment: it is telling you that the provided path is incorrect, try providing the full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory separator is wrong.
Instead of '\\' use '/'
This should work:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import random
import numpy as np

path = r"/home/laa/Desktop/TheLab/nft/Emojis"
a=random.choice(os.listdir(path))
print(a)

file = path+'/'+a
Image.open(file).show()
```

If this still doesn't work try adding the previous directories or drives before \home. eg. C:/Users/dr_de/Documents (the whole path)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Linux style `/` and Windows style `\\` path separators. The easiest way is to use

```
import os
...
file = os.path.join(path,a)
```

which should insert the right character for you, I assume it needs to be a '/' .

Comment: OMG!!Im so dumb I haven't even noticed.Thank u very much!!